# Presto - How to convert a field with map<string,string> to rows

Tags: sql, arrays, presto

I'm new to Presto SQL and I am stuck to a issue and I really need your help.

I have a table with a field "Info":

```
Date                  Info
2021-01-01            {"user_id":"12345", "order_id": "[333222, 444555, 777888]"}
2021-01-02            {"user_id":"67891", "order_id": "[948263]"}
2021-01-03            {"user_id":"93846", "order_id": "[937846, 889213, 886534, 991827]"}
2021-01-04            {"user_id":"63792", "order_id": "[]"}
2021-01-05            {"user_id":"04937", "order_id": "[837462, 837213]"}
```

I want to pull all order_id(s) and convert them as rows, the output may look like this:

```
Date                  order_id
2021-01-01            333222
2021-01-01            444555
2021-01-01            777888
2021-01-02            948263
2021-01-03            937846
...
2021-01-05            837213
```

My query:

```
SELECT Date, Info['ORDER_ID']
FROM test_table
```

I tried the query above but it can only returns the order_id as an array. Anyone know how to do it? Thank you so much and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation is you friend. You are interested in [json functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html) and [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) (in the code sample succinct version of syntax is used). In addition to this there is one trick - `"[333222, 444555, 777888]"` is a double encoded json array, so you need to parse it two times (first one is done by `json_extract_scalar`):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (Date, Info) AS (
   VALUES ('2021-01-01', '{"user_id":"12345", "order_id": "[333222, 444555, 777888]"}')
)

-- query
select Date, order_id
from dataset,
unnest (cast(json_parse(json_extract_scalar(Info, '$.order_id')) as array(integer))) as t(order_id);
```

Output:

| Date | order_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 333222 |
| 2021-01-01 | 444555 |
| 2021-01-01 | 777888 |

**UPD**

To address your question in the comments:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (Date, Info) AS (
   VALUES ('2021-01-01', map(array['user_id', 'order_id'], array['12345', '[333222, 444555, 777888]']))
)

-- query
select Date, order_id
from dataset,
    unnest (cast(json_parse(Info['order_id']) as array(integer))) as t(order_id);
```

Comment: Hi @Guru Stron, since my actual data type is map<string,string> and when I applied the query above, it returned "No applicable overloads for function 'json_extract_scalar' with arguments '(Mapping[string?, string?]?, string)'". Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @Jancos then you need to process it as a map, just extract value from it instead of using `json_extract_scalar`.